# Is there any closed form for the following series?

Tags: generating-functions, closed-form

I am looking for any closed form expression for the series given below:
$$ \sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{(xy)^m}{m(1-y^m)}. $$

Comment: Does $\displaystyle \sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{(xy)^m}{m(1-y^m)} = \sum_{m,n \ge 1} \frac{x^my^{{mn}}}{m} = -\sum_{n \ge 1} \log (1-xy^n) = -\log \left(\prod_{n \ge 1} (1-xy^n)\right)$ help ?

Comment: I don't want 'infinite product' here.

Comment: Without considering its exponential as done by r9m, we cannot do much better than $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{x^d}{d}\right) y^n.$$

Comment: I guess so. the beginning of this question was $$ \sum_{n≥1} ( \sum_{d|n} \frac{x^d}{d}) y^n $$ which comes from the counting of the n-permutations $ \{tau} $ with $ \{tau}^n=id$.

Comment: ${\tau}$ with  ${\tau}^n=id$

Answer (score 4):

A closed for exists (attachment bellow) for the sum :
$$ \sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{(xy)^m}{(1-y^m)} $$
thanks to the special function called q-digamma. See : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html

By integration, a closed form for the sum :
$$ \sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{(xy)^m}{m(1-y^m)} $$
is formally expressed.

I cannot say if a simpler form can be derived.

[image]