# What closed forms exist for this basic hypergeometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function, q-analogs

I've run into:

$$\sum_{x=1}^n {x^a\over 1-q^{x}}, \ s.t.\ q\in \mathbb N>1 \ or \ q\in (0, 1),\  a \in \mathbb N$$

I am interested mostly in the cases where $a = 1$  or $ a = 2$

Things I've done so far: reference a few places on basic hypergeometric series, not limited to something that looks remotely like what I'm interested in:
[Take a look at the "Simple Series" section, the first example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_hypergeometric_series)

EDIT: I've made *some* progress, please see: [JJacquelin's answer to this question, can someone help get their attention (I cannot comment yet)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091560/is-there-any-closed-form-for-the-following-series/1233278#1233278). If we cannot, should not, or do not wish to get their attention through contact, perhaps explaining some of the manipulations in their answer might help us here. For example, pulling out the $1 \over m$ from the sum in the second to last line to obtain the integral shown, why was that done? What technique would apply if it were $1 \over m!$ instead?

Secondly, I've found that theta functions may be involved somehow:[See GEdgar's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60311/infinite-series-of-the-form-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1ak1?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well as [Paramanand Singh's answer here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760270/closed-form-of-an-integral-involving-a-jacobi-theta-function-int-0-infty?rq=1)

Comment: Do you really want $q \in \mathbb N$?  If you're taking about series in powers of $q$, you should rather take $|q| < 1$.  In any case, $q=1$ certainly doesn't work.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Some thorough editing would have saved both of us some time with the way I asked.  $0 < q<1$ does indeed work if I reframe the original line of thinking that led me here.  $1$ should indeed be removed from the domain.

Comment: edited the question to reflect comments